# how to speed up plotting of MULTIPOLYGON sf objecs

Tags: performance, plot

I am looking for a way to speed up the plots of MULTIPOLYGON sf objects,
for example to plot an object of about 1Mb size in memory, took around 39 seconds:

```
> system.time(plot(st_geometry(munis_sf)))
    user  system elapsed 
   1.068   1.447  39.432
```

and produced this plot

[plot of a MULTIPOLYGON sf object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0Zho.png)

is there a way to produce the same plot, but much more quickly?

thanks in advance,
Ramón